# Buffer for a 3 digit number

Tags: c

I want to create a buffer for a 3 digit number, status, and the null characters. Currently I have

```
char buf[4];
sprintf(buf, "%d",status);
```

My question is whether this is sufficient size for a 3 digit number, which is returned as the status from [waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

Comment: What data type is `status`? No data type in C guarantees a range of 0-999 inclusive. You need to add some kind of check. If status is a `char`, then it's range is 0-255 inclusive. If a short (generally), 0-2^16 inclusive (not a 3-digit number).

Comment: @Linuxios status is the return value from waitpid()

Comment: I'm pretty sure waitpid can return a lot more because it also has various flags in the upper bits to indicate things like killed by signal. Regardless though, `snprintf` is always at least as good as `sprintf` and often much better, so it is a good habit to get into.

Comment: I would change this line: sprintf(buf, "%d",status); to: sprintf(buf, "%3d",status%1000); just incase the status value is greater than 999 and if you want the number with leading 0s then: sprintf(buf, "%03d",status%1000);  Note: I'm assuming that status will always be >= 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but there's nothing preventing the user (or however `status` is filled in) from punching in a lot more than three digits and overflowing that little buffer.

The `snprintf` function should be used instead, it will cut off input that is too long:

```
snprintf(buf, 4, "%d", status); // the 4 is the length of buf
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes: 3 characters/digits and the trailing null.

Answer (score 0):

Better be safe than sorry.

If you want it be safe, make sure it really 3 digits number.

For example you can use mod operator:

```
char buf[4];
sprintf(buf, "%d",status % 1000);
```

Note that if you choose the `snprintf` solution, and you give 1001, you'll get result of 100, if you use this solution you'll get 1.

You can choose what is more suitable for you.

You can also combine the both:

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d",status % 1000);
```

Comment: You must use `snprintf`.  If status has the value `-900`, you'll get "-900\0" placed in your buffer, which is one character too many.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe for a strictly three digit decimal, but `waitpid()` makes no such guarantees;  the type `pid_t` is a 32 bit signed integer, and three digits seems a somewhat optimistic assumption.  Y

You should range check the `waitpid()` return value to guarantee that it will fit in your buffer, but it is generally unnecessary to be quite so sparing with memory; a buffer of 12 characters will allow any 32 bit signed integer to be represented as a decimal string (worst case 10 digits, a sign character and a nul terminator).  Similarly for 16 bit, use 7 and 64 bit use 23.  In general:

decimal_string_buffer_len = ceil( log( 2 <sup>sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT</sup>)) + 3